# change the style of all pages in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have created a personal website. The default color of the website is black. I want to allow the user to change the color to "red,green.blue,..."

I have done this using jQuery. by changing the stylesheet (the css file)

This is my code:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){


            $("img.black").click(function(){
                $('link').attr('href','style_black.css');
            });
            $("img.red").click(function(){
                $('link').attr('href','style_red.css');

            });
            $("img.blue").click(function(){
                $('link').attr('href','style_blue.css');

            });
            });
```

but the problem is when I go to another page in the same website the color returns to the default (black)

for example: I'm in (profile) page and I change the color then I go to (contact) page, the color returns to the default !

Is there a way to change the color for the whole website? (for all pages in the website)

Thanks

Comment: Web pages by default are stateless. You'd need to store the change someplace like with a cookie, localstorage, or a database.

Comment: how to do that? Is there a link or a lesson explaining that? Thanks buddy

Comment: If you do a Google search for 'how to set a cookie,' one or two results may come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the selection in a cookie or on the backend server somewhere. You could, for example, use a [jQuery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to store the cookie, and then do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Read style selection from cookie
    var style = $.cookie("style");
    // Options to store cookie for 365 days for all pages
    var options = { expires: 365, path: "/" };
    // If style was stored in cookie, apply it
    if(typeof style !== "undefined") {
        $("link").attr("href","style_"+style+".css");
    }
    $("img.black").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href","style_black.css");
        $.cookie("style","black", options);
    });
    $("img.red").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href","style_red.css");
        $.cookie("style","red", options);
    });
    $("img.blue").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href","style_blue.css");
        $.cookie("style","blue", options);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have uploaded the plugin to my website. and I copied & pasted your code but it's not working. Sorry I'm really new to cookies and JavaScript. Any explanation or links would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: jQuery-cookie page has good explanation on how the plugin works. My example stores the selection in a session cookie for the current path. You need to look into `expires` and `path` settings for the cookie plugin to make the selection more persistent. I will edit my answer to reflect this.